# How to compare an array of strings in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare, string-comparison

I want to see if two arrays of strings are equal.

Eg:

`compare(["abc", "def"], ["def", "abc"])`

should return `true` and similarly,

```
compare(["abc", "def"], ["def", "ghi"])
```

should return `false`.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please provide the code where your are attempting this

Comment: Either sort the arrays and compare a[n] to b[n], or skip sorting and look for a[n] in every position of b.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

```
JSON.stringify(array1.sort()) === JSON.stringify(array2.sort())
```

Comment: very cool for primitives, but watch out for many pitfalls https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/compare-arrays

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript doesn't have a Set or Multiset data structure (at least, not one with wide browser support), which is what you'd normally use for testing that two sets of items are the same regardless of order. So I recommend sorting the arrays and checking that their contents are equal. If you know the arrays contain only strings, you can check the items with simple equality:

```
function compare(array1, array2) {
  if (array1.length != array2.length) {
    return false;
  }

  array1 = array1.slice();
  array1.sort();
  array2 = array2.slice();
  array2.sort();

  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i] != array2[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(compare(["abc", "def"], ["def", "abc"])); // true
console.log(compare(["abc", "def"], ["def", "ghi"])); // false
```

For more general cases, you'll need a more complex definition of equality, and I recommend browsing the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript).

Comment: I think you have a problem with the logic in `if (array1[i] != array2[i]) {
      return false;    }`. You don;t want to break if match not found,  you should keep looking a match

Comment: it looks they have to be considered equals if they contain the same items, even if in a different order. This won't pass your check. Gonna be a n^2 iteration... or will need sorting as you implemented.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. Is this the most efficient way? Doesn't JS have any built in function for this operation?

Comment: I think I addressed your comments. I originally misread the question and expected the arrays to be exactly equal. Now I use the same approach as Culme and sort the arrays.

Comment: Abhijith: I usually use this approach. In extreme cases I will put all the items from `array1` as keys in an Object (the closest thing JavaScript has to a Set data structure) to get constant-time lookup when iterating through `array2`, but I've hardly ever needed to.

Answer (score 3):

Naive algorithm: O(N^2)

```
function compare(array1, array2){
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
    if (array2.indexOf(array1[i]) < 0) return false;
  }
  return true;  
}
```

Better one: (uses sorting, O(NLOGN))

```
function compare(array1, array2){
  array1.sort();
  array2.sort();
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
    if (array1[i] !== array2[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;  
}
```

Comment: Both of these need `if(array1.length !== array2.length) { return false }` at the start for them to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following ES6-oneliner

```
const compare = (a1, a2) =>
  (a1 = new Set(a1)) &&
  (a2 = new Set(a2)) &&
  a1.size === a2.size &&
  [...a1].every(v => a2.has(v));
```

1. Remove duplicates by converting arrays to Sets (for `compare(['a', 'a'], ['a', 'b'])` should return `false`).
2. Length comparison (for `compare(['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])` should return `false`).
3. Check if the first set items are present in the second set.

Comment: This would return true for `a1 = ['foo', 'foo']` and `a2 = ['foo', 'bar'];`

Comment: @StephenHarris Thank you! I applied `Set` converting to resolve duplicates situation.

Answer (score 0):

Unified solution:

```
function compare(a, b){
      var isEqual = false;  
      if (Array.isArray(a) && Array.isArray(b) && a.length == b.length){
          a.sort();
          b.sort();
          var i;
          for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
              if (a[i] === b[i]){
                  isEqual = true;
              } else{
                  isEqual = false;
                  break;
              }
          }

      }
      return isEqual;
}

var arr1 = ["def", "abc"], arr2 = ["abc", "def"];
console.log(compare(arr2,arr1)); // gives 'true'

console.log(compare(["abc", "def"], ["def", "ghi"])); // gives 'false'
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ob7e5ye5/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
function compare(arr1, arr2){
    var match = true
    if(arr1.length != arr2.length){
        match = false
    }
    arr1 = arr1.slice();
    arr1.sort();
    arr2.slice();
    arr2.sort();
    for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
        if(arr1[i] != arr2[i]){
            match = false;
        }
    }
    return match;
}

console.log(compare(["abc", "def"], ["def", "abc"])); // it will return true
console.log(compare(["abc", "def"], ["def", "ghi"])); // it will return false
```

Answer (score 0):

Verbose typescript example for ordered or unordered
(obviously inspired by @dhilts [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54186168/2919380))

```
const VERBOSE = console.log // ()=>void

const areDeduplicatedArraysEqualUnordered = (a1: any[] | Set<any>, a2: any[] | Set<any>) => {
    (a1 = new Set(a1)); (a2 = (new Set(a2))); VERBOSE('checking arrays as Sets', { a1, a2 })
    return !!(a1.size === a2.size && [...a1].every(v => (a2 as Set<any>).has(v)))
}
const areDeduplicatedArraysEqualOrdered = (a1: any[], a2: any[]) => {
    (a1 = [...(new Set(a1))] as any[]) && (a2 = [...(new Set(a2))] as any[]) && VERBOSE('checking deduplicated arrays', { a1, a2 })
    return !!(a1.length === a2.length && a1.every((v: any, i) => a2[i] === v))
}

const a2 = [3,5,8]
const a1 = [8,5,3]
const notEqual = areDeduplicatedArraysEqualOrdered(a1,a2)
const yesEqual = areDeduplicatedArraysEqualUnordered(a1,a2)
VERBOSE('results', { notEqual, yesEqual})
```